# Is there a way to directly access the built-in types of starlark language in Bazel?

Tags: bazel, starlark

For example, is there a way to call the constructor of File class to create an instance of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it just depends on the thing you want. Some things like File you have to go through an API, for example to create a file object in a rule function, you would use `ctx.actions.declare_file(filename)`

See this for examples: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#declare_file

Other things you can create directly, like `depset` has `depset()`. See global functions here https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/skylark-overview.html

Comment: I guess I made a bad example of my question.  Can I create an File object?

Comment: gotcha, I edited my answer to reflect your edits to the question